# Como lidar com mensagens de erro 400

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, rest, mobile

Trabalho com um aplicativo feito em xamarin que envia diversas requisições para a api. Eventualmente, uma ação do usuário recebe uma BAD REQUEST porque o usuário tentou curtiu uma foto que ela já havia curtido antes, ou tenta seguir outro usuário que ela já seguia e por algum motivo o app não mostrava que já estava curtindo/seguindo. E esse erro acaba logado como um crash. Minha dúvida é se devo dar um catch nesse erro e suprimir, ou se deixo logado como erro mesmo. Para o usuário não muda nada, a experiência do app continua a mesma, sem erro, sem crash.

Comment: Trate o erro com o `try...catch` e retorne o erro — de forma simples —, para o usuário ficara ciente que ouve um erro durante aquela ação.

Comment: Mas eu não quero que o usuário saiba do erro nem seja informado. Quero que o fluxo continue como se nada tivesse acontecido. Na verdade, já é assim, Mas quando vou olhar nos logs e no relatório do erro, ele conta como um crash.

Comment: Então adicione um `try { ... } catch(Exception ignored) {}` para ignorar uma `Exception`